# NullPointException in ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I am displaying a ListView in my Android progam using an ArrayAdapter to get data from a string array.  Normally, I get data from an InputStream to fill the string array and the ListView displays properly.  However, if my InputStream is empty I initialized my array with a string value.  When this happens I get a NullPointException when applying the arrayadapter to my listview.
Here is how I initialize my string array.

```
    protected String[] doInBackground(Void...parameters ) {
  .........  do something
   String[] result = new String[50];
   result[0] = "No restaurants found in this area";
      .......  get my httpconnection
```

This is how I populate the string array:

```
  ........
  if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    InputStream in = httpConnection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(in));
  String line;

int x=0;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

    result[x] = line;

    x++;
} 

    return result;
   }
```

This is where I create my Listview:

```
   protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {

        ListView restaurant_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.restaurant_list);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listview, R.id.viewtext, result);
        restaurant_list.setAdapter(arrayAdpt);

    }
```

If I get data from my input stream everything works.  If I don't get any data, the string array contains only my initialization values and the program bombs at the list.setAdapter(arrayAdpt) line (last line). Also, this processing is being done under an asynchronous task (AsynTask) under the doInBackground method. Why should the source of my data in the string array make a difference in how the arrayadapter works?  Anyone have suggestions?

Ok.  I changed my logic to use

```
 List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
 .....
 result.add(line);
 .....
  return (String[]) result.toArray();
```

And it gives me a nullexception I would assume at the return instruction since the error is in the doInBackground method.  Below is the errors from the logcat.

```
  03-09 20:03:13.755: E/AndroidRuntime(6089): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
  03-09 20:03:13.755: E/AndroidRuntime(6089): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
  03-09 20:03:13.755: E/AndroidRuntime(6089):   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
  03-09 20:03:13.755: E/AndroidRuntime(6089):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
  03-09 20:03:13.755: E/AndroidRuntime(6089):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
  03-09 20:03:13.755: E/AndroidRuntime(6089):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
  03-09 20:03:13.755: E/AndroidRuntime(6089):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
   03-09 20:03:13.755: E/AndroidRuntime(6089):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
   03-09 20:03:13.755: E/AndroidRuntime(6089):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
   03-09 20:03:13.755: E/AndroidRuntime(6089):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
   03-09 20:03:13.755: E/AndroidRuntime(6089): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]
   03-09 20:03:13.755: E/AndroidRuntime(6089):  at com.example.herb4.MainActivity$GetRestaurant.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:173)
   03-09 20:03:13.755: E/AndroidRuntime(6089):  at com.example.herb4.MainActivity$GetRestaurant.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
   03-09 20:03:13.755: E/AndroidRuntime(6089):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
   03-09 20:03:13.755: E/AndroidRuntime(6089):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
```

Answer (score 0):

> if my InputStream is empty I initialized my array with a string value

In this case you are getting  `NullPointException` exception because you have created an String Array of `Size 50` but adding only one item at `0th position` .

to avoid `NullPointException` exception use `ArrayList` instead of Array if you don't known how much items u are getting from webservice instead of static size array.

**Example :-**

```
ArrayList<String> result=new ArrayList<String>();

if(<Stream not empty>){

  //Add all elemnts to ArrayList
  result.add(line);
}
else{

   result.add("No restaurants found in this area");

 }
```

Comment: But I don't fill the array when I read from the input buffer.  So should I initialize all entries in the string array?  Seems like a lot of extra work.

Comment: @Dave : why u are not able to add items to ArrayList? just use `result.add(line)` instead of  `result[x] = line;`

Comment: I have tried ArrayList using: List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(); but it also gave me a nullexception, even when getting input data into the stream.  I am making the conversion from C# to Java so pardon me for being naive in some areas.  One thing I don't understand is that the debugger will not follow into my ascychronous task so I have to wing it as to what caused the problem.

Comment: I did use result.add(line) and  also used: return (String[]) result.toArray(); and it caused a nullexception.  I can try it again and see if I can narrow it down as to where it bombs.

Comment: @Dave : use ArrayList instead of Array and if still getting error  then plz add logcat result with question. and if you are extending ListActivity then plz make sure u have ListView id in xml as `android:id="@android:id/list"`

Comment: @Dave : why you are casting ArrayList to Array just change doInBackground method return type to `ArrayList<String>` ,`onPostExecute(String[] result)` to `onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result)` and `AsyncTask<?, ?, ArrayList<String>>`

Comment: @Dave : and to convert ArrayList to Array use `return (String[]) result.toArray(new String[0]);` instead  `return (String[]) result.toArray();`

Comment: I used: return (ArrayList<String>) result;  instead and it worked!  Thanks very much for your help in leading me through the Java wilderness.

Comment: @Dave : if this answer help u in solving current issue then mark it as answer . Thanks